# Scrollable textview inside tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a `UITextView` inside a `UITableViewCell`. `UITextView` text is appearing only for the first few visible cells and then disappearing on scroll.

If TextView scrolling is disabled, everything is working properly. So this is because of
having a scrollview(textview's) inside another scrollview(tableview's)

Is there a way with scrollable textview with fixed height inside a tableview cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CustomCell else { return CustomCell() }

    cell.myTextView.text = cellData.text
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Add the height constraint of your `textView`. Then the height of the `textView` will be fixed inside your `tableViewCell`.

Comment: the height is already fixed. I want a scrollable textview inside a tableview. with the textview text appearing properly

Comment: Can you add code/screenshots of the current behaviour?

Comment: Show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: Added code for cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Show your CustomCell class code.

Comment: Just the outlets.

Comment: What does your `cellData.text` holds? Just a static string?

Comment: yes just string